# insert an sd card before using the camera android emulator

Tags: android

When i open camera in my Android emulator. I get message insert an sd card before using the camera android emulator

[image]

Here is my configuration of emulator

[image]

My android studio version is

> Android Studio 2.3.3 Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017 JRE:
>   1.8.0_92-b14 amd64 JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: As most SD cards are measured in GB, not MB, you probably need to increase the size allocated. My old Galaxy S3 was 64GB, and my current S8 is 256GB. Did you consider trying that?

Comment: @ken i try increase size to 1GB but error still happen.

Comment: Once again: My 5+ year old Galaxy S3 was **64GB**, my current S8 is **256GB**. Why would you expect **1GB** to be enough? Try a reasonable amount. Stop nitpicking storage if you want to use the camera. 1 GB is a speck of data on the disk when dealing with modern high-res cameras.

Comment: But i have some another emulator, they working perfect, and SD card of them only 100 MB. This error only happen on Nexus S emulator ( not happen on Pixel emulator and other). I try delete this Nexus S emulator and recreate , this error still happen

Comment: I see the same problem on Nexus 5X, not sure of the others.  Using default 100MB.  Emulators are too slow to be wasting time trying different sizes.  So switching to Pixel based on OPs comment.